# How to create a hash of an arbitrary data with Parity substrate

Tags: parity, substrate

I would like to know how to create a hash of a string with substrate. I really don't get which files to include to get the thing working. I've followed this https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/creating-your-first-substrate-chain without success.

Comment: It seems you may have found an old tutorial. Try this: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/next/tutorials/creating-your-first-substrate-chain/

Comment: that tutorial has 0 code examples it's just compiling and starting the node

Comment: I'm sorry, please combine that with: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/next/tutorials/build-a-dapp/

Comment: You can find all the tutorials at: https://substrate.dev/en/tutorials

Answer (score 4):

In the Substrate runtime, you have access to a generic type `T::Hashing` defined by FRAME System:

```
/// The hashing system (algorithm) being used in the runtime (e.g. Blake2).
type Hashing: Hash<Output = Self::Hash>;
```

This means you always have access and the API of the `Hash` trait: https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/master/sp_runtime/traits/trait.Hash.html

```
fn hash(s: &[u8]) -> Self::Output

Produce the hash of some byte-slice.
```

So if you take some arbitrary bytes, you can always get the hash by doing:

```
let data_hash = T::Hashing::hash(data);
```